# Compiling VIM on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: vim, osx-mountain-lion

Compiling VIM on Mountain Lion does not work for me. I compile VIM with the following sequence:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim
./configure --enable-rubyinterp --with-features=huge -prefix=/usr
make
```

I then try to start the compiled binary with `src/vim`, but it crashes like this:

```
$ src/vim
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: TIP: You can use macports to install VIM if you want.

Comment: Other issues notwithstanding, shouldn't `-prefix` be `--prefix` instead?

Comment: If you're experimenting I'd recommend --prefix=$HOME so when you 'make install' it just puts files in ~/share and ~/bin (you don't need sudo and you can alias vi=~/bin/vim as you please). I've done this in the past as mac vims command line :version feature list wasn't what I needed.

Answer (score -5):

**DON'T COMPILE VIM ON MAC OS X.**

It's a total waste of time.

The easiest and most reliable way to run Vim on Mac OS X is to download and install [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/). Some of the advantages are:

- you'll be up and running in less time than it takes to run `./configure`,
- it's compiled with all the features you'd need,
- it can work with any Python or Ruby,
- it doesn't touch any system files,
- it's a lot faster than anything you might finally be able to build by yourself.

You can even run it in a terminal with the included `mvim` script.

Vim is also available through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).

Unless you *really* want to mess around with the source code, of course. In which case you should probably look at the output of `configure`: maybe you are missing some libs.